# iterating a map and replaceing values

Tags: java, sql, spring, dictionary

I have a complex join query where I need to replace attributes of the query according to the name provided in the table. I have a map that has a key as an attribute to be replaced in the query and the value of the map contains the values to get replaced.

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("key1", "attribute1");
map1.put("key2", "attribute2");
map1.put("key12", "attribute3");

String query = "Select * from values where key in ('key1','key2','key12')";
map1.forEach((k,v) -> {
    query = query.replaceAll(k,v);
});
```

This one replaces `key1`, `key2` correctly but in the case of `key12`, it replaces `key1` and adds `2` with the attribute i.e. `attribute12` which is wrong.

Can anyone please suggest how to correct this? I have provided an example of a simple query but I need to replace values in many complex dynamic queries. A similar problem happens for `key21`.

Comment: You can simply surround your key with some separators, for instance "{key12}" instead of "key12". Please note also that your code is absolutely not sql-injection proof.

Answer (score 0):

One way to make this work would be to use a template-engine like approach. E.g. surround your keys with `{` and `}`.

**Edit2**

This is a working example in Java. Keep in mind that this is not really a great approach for SQL statements, as others have pointed out.

```java
final Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("{key1}", "attribute1");
map1.put("{key2}", "attribute2");
map1.put("{key12}", "attribute3");

String query = "Select * from values where key in ('{key1}','{key2}','{key12}')";
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map1.entrySet()) {
    query = query.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
System.out.println(query);
```

---

**Edit**

As @Benoit pointed out: This is definitely not SQL injection proof. You would need to escape the attributes to make this safe.

Comment: That answers the question for sure, but please note that this code is not sql injection proof. [More on that topic](https://avinetworks.com/glossary/sql-injection-attack/).

Comment: You are right @Benoit, I just made an edit.

Comment: It doesn't compile as `query` is neither final nor effectively-final.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis OPs code did not compile either before his edit, so I just added the correct quotation marks and the curly braces. You are right, I should have tested my code. An edit is on the way :)

Comment: "OPs code did not compile either" - don't use the OP's code to justify your code, which is wrong. Most of the questions provide a code that doesn't compile. Moreover, I edited the OP's code (at least quotes and some grammar) but it doesn't compile anyway. Please fix your code and I am more than happy to upovte your answer. Consider retracting a vote on mine as I'd like to hear what's wrong there if there is a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is dangerous. The correct filling the query with the parameters is through using classes and methods designed to do so, ex. `TypedQuery<T>`:

```
// assuming EntityManager em and Map<String, String> map

TypedQuery<Whatever> query = em.createQuery(
      "Select whateverClassName from values where key in (':key1',':key2',':key12')", 
      Whatever.class);

// you need to iterate through the entries anyway
for (final Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map1.entrySet()) {
    query.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

If you use a `Collection<String>` or its subtype instead, you can pass it to the parameters directly with no hassle:

```
List<String> params = Arrays.asList("attribute1", "attribute2", "attribute3");
TypedQuery<Whatever> query = em.createQuery(
      "Select whateverClassName from values where key in (:params)", Whatever.class);
query.setParameter("params", params);
```

---

If you insist on using your way, then you should wrap the parameters in something fairly unique such as `${...}` and replace the values using Regex:

```
String query = "Select * from values where key in ('${key1}','${key2}','${key12}')";
for (final Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map1.entrySet()) {
    String key = "\\$\\{" + entry.getKey() + "}";
    query = query.replaceAll(key, entry.getValue());
}
```

Using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) and newer, [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) using [`Stream#reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) is also a nice way to go:

```
String query = "Select * from values where key in ('${key1}','${key2}','${key12}')";
String queryWithParameters = map1.entrySet()
    .stream().reduce(
            query,
            (q, e) -> q.replaceAll("\\$\\{" + e.getKey() + "}", e.getValue()),
            (l, r) -> l);
```

**Disclaimer:** Remember that none of these solutions is safe against SQL injection and they are error-prone. I highly recommend using `TypedQuery<T>` instead.

Comment: In my opinion, this is overkill, because OPs question was just "how to replace strings with attributes stored in a map" and not how to properly write SQL statements in Java. A sidenote as warning seems to be enough in my opinion :)

Comment: I provided a solution based on what is the OP trying to **and** the recommended one. The OP is free to make a choice.

Comment: Thanks a ton  Nikolas Charalambidis..your suggestion has helped me  to correct my approach..